# How to set the border color for visual material entry using xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

We are using the visual material entry for our project.

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Material.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomMaterialEntryRenderer ), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace MyApp.Android
{
    public class CustomMaterialEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

How to set the border color for entry?

Comment: Do you mean you want change the underline color ?

Comment: No. I want change border color for indication

Comment: Did you try to use `PlaceholderColor `?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a style

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">{color}</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">{strokeWidth}</item>
</style>
```

To set the style in whole application

```
<item name="textInputStyle">@style/TextInputLayoutTheme</item>
```

If you want to use the style only in some controls you must create the native control in renderer and pass the style by constructor